# Error on @import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables"

Tags: sass, gulp, bootstrap-4

We use microsoft VSTS build and release pipeline. Everything was working fine until 2 days ago. We faced an interesting issue when running a gulp script to compile SASS using Yarn.

I kept on failing with this error:

```
> 2018-03-14T05:23:42.3498877Z >> @import
> "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
> 2018-03-14T05:23:42.3498877Z    ^ 2018-03-14T05:23:42.3498877Z 
> 2018-03-14T05:23:42.3498877Z     at options.error
> (F:\agentA\_work\1\s\prototype\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
```

As soon as we ran these commands below on Build server it started working:

```
npm i -g yarn  
npm i -g gulp
```

Questions:

1. Any idea why above command would fix the problem?
2. Before the fix we looked whether bootstrap and all files existed on build server. They definitely were there. And still build failed until we ran above command. I wonder why it failed.

Thanks